# android copy database from assets folder

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I having trouble coping a database from the assets folder to the databases folder. When the user start the application I check if the database doesnt exists and if true I copy the database.

Where is my code:

```
    private void CopyDatabaseIfNotExists() {

        dbName = "quizdb.db";

        File f = getDatabasePath(dbName);
        if (f.exists())
            return;

        System.out.println("db missing");

        try {

            InputStream mInputStream = getAssets().open(dbName);

            OutputStream mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = mInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            mOutputStream.flush();
            mOutputStream.close();
            mInputStream.close();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And I got this error:

```
06-15 12:29:04.882  25037-25037/com.ex.example W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.ex.example/databases/quizdb.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I already tried search for the soluction but cant find. Somebody can help me? Thanks and sorry my english.

Comment: Please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) rather than rolling your own solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileOutputStream` throws this exception when the file does not exist **and** cannot be created. I had this probelm before and managed to solve it by first calling `openOrCreateDatabase` method of the `Context` object (or `SQLiteDatabase` class) before `OutputStream mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);`

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, what you said its 100% correct I just addded this two lines before the `InputStream` and now this works fine `Context context = getApplicationContext();
            context.openOrCreateDatabase("quizdb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);` To finish can you say if im calling the `openOrCreateDatabase` correctly?

Comment: The way you are calling it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...its work for me..!! and you sure you have put database  file in assets folder..!!

```
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Log.v("Tag assets",is.toString());
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    Log.v("Tag assets", out.toString());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        // Log.v("Tag",out.toString());
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        // Log.v("Tag",out.toString());
    }
    // Log.v("Tag","Database created");
    is.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();      

}
```

Comment: its path ,where you have to store your database file in device , like    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.yourapplication/databases/";

Comment: I'm pretty sure Android Studio yells at you not to hardcode `/data/data/`